# How do I change the color of (in)active document windows in Windows 10

Tags: windows, colors, documents

I was reading the article below, and I also want to change the colors of the **IN**active document window and the **Ac**tive document window. So, WITHIN an application, not the applications themselves.
I would like them to look like the attached picture, dark blue for active and light blue for inactive.

I want this because the present colors hard differ from each other, so it's harder to see, especially for someone with limited eye sight, and outdoor situations.

How do I do that, is there a similar registry hack for this? (like the one in the article below) This used to be easy in Winxp-Vista Win7 but not in Win10.

[image: Application with one **IN**active document window and one **Ac**tive document window]

http://www.howtogeek.com/258162/how-to-add-color-to-inactive-title-bars-in-windows-10/